# Create Azure Container Instance with Registry in Python

Tags: python, azure

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I am currently working on a project where I need to create an Azure Container instance using an image from the Azure Container Registry. Additionally, I need to run a shell command within this container. I am attempting to implement this functionality using Python.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import argparse
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.containerinstance import ContainerInstanceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.containerregistry import ContainerRegistryManagementClient
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Create a container in Azure using client credentials.")
parser.add_argument("--client-id", required=True, help="Azure Active Directory client ID")
parser.add_argument("--client-secret", required=True, help="Azure Active Directory client secret")
parser.add_argument("--tenant-id", required=True, help="Azure Active Directory tenant ID")
parser.add_argument("--container-name", required=True, help="Name for the container")
parser.add_argument("--container-resource-group", required=True, help="Resource group name")
parser.add_argument("--command", required=True, help="Command to run inside the container")
parser.add_argument("--image", required=True, help="Container image to use")
parser.add_argument("--subscription-id", required=False, help="Azure subscription ID (optional, uses environment variable by default)")
parser.add_argument("--cpu-request", required=True, help="CPU request for the container (e.g., 0.5 for half a core)")
parser.add_argument("--memory-request", required=True, help="Memory request for the container (e.g., 1Gi)")

args = parser.parse_args()

def create_container(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id, container_name, resource_group_name, command, image, subscription_id=None, cpu_request=None, memory_request=None):
    if not subscription_id:
        subscription_id = os.environ.get("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID")
        if not subscription_id:
            raise ValueError("Subscription ID is required, either provide it as an argument or set the AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID environment variable.")

    # Authenticate to Azure Container Registry (ACR)
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        tenant_id=tenant_id
    )

    acr_client = ContainerRegistryManagementClient(credential, subscription_id=subscription_id)

    # Get the ACR
    acr_name = ""  # Replace with the name of your ACR
    acr = acr_client.registries.get(resource_group_name, acr_name)

    # Use the registry in the ACR
    registry_login_server = f"{acr.login_server}"
    registry_username = f"{acr.admin_user_enabled}"
    registry_password = f"{acr.admin_user_password}"

    # Create the Container Instance
    client = ContainerInstanceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id=subscription_id)

    container_group = client.container_groups.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name,
        container_name,
        {
            "location": "eastus",  # Replace with your desired Azure region
            "os_type": "Linux",  # Specify Linux as the OS type
            "containers": [
                {
                    "name": container_name,
                    "properties": {
                        "image": f"{registry_login_server}/{image}",
                        "command": [command],
                        "resources": {
                            "requests": {
                                "cpu": 2,
                                "MemoryinGB": 6
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ).result()

    print(f"Container '{container_name}' created with ID: {container_group.id}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_container(
        args.client_id,
        args.client_secret,
        args.tenant_id,
        args.container_name,
        args.container_resource_group,
        args.command,
        args.image,
        args.subscription_id,
        args.cpu_request,
        args.memory_request
    )
```

but above code is giving error:

```
Code: InaccessibleImage
Message: The image '<or>.azurecr.io/<image>:<tag>' in container group 'container name' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credentials.
```

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on improving or debugging this code. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The error is indicating that there is an issue with accessing the container image from the Azure Container Registry, this could be due to incorrect registry credentials or incorrect image name.

Comment: @VenkatV The Registry Image and Credentials both are fine. FYI

Comment: i am not sure where registry credentials are being used

Comment: If possible, please send a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: I am not able to paste a screenshot here

Comment: pasted ss in question. please check

Comment: Kindly share the full error message screenshot, along with the values you're passing in the cmd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256909/discussion-between-aman-chagti-and-venkat-v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to create an Azure Container instance using an image from the Azure Container Registry. Additionally, I need to run a shell command within this container.

Alternatively, you can also create an `Azure Container instance` with an `ACR` image using **Azure CLI** cmdlets on Linux

Create and save the bash file `container.sh` on a Linux `VM` with the below script and give permission to the file using the command `chmod +x container.sh`. Then you can run the script using `./container.sh`.

Create another file named `script.sh` that you want to run in the container, and then copy the file path under the `--command-line` section

```bash
 #!/bin/bash
   
   # Login to Azure Container Registry (ACR)
   az acr login --name "demoacrtesttest" --username "demoacrtesttest" --password "8Sk22GDCmd34djgoeu2q2FzQszMXMdFn1XaBYSqdFX+ACRC3jPMH"
   
   # Create Azure Container Instance
   az container create \
       --resource-group "<RG-Name>" \
       --name "samplecontainer" \
       --image "<ACRName>.azurecr.io/venkatsampleimage/nginx:v3" \
       --os-type "Linux" \
       --cpu "2" \
       --memory "3.5" \
       --command-line  "/bin/sh -c '/path to/myscript.sh'"
```

**Output:**

[image]

After running the script, the azure container instance has been created using an image from the `Azure Container Registry`

[image]
**Reference:** [Azure Container Instances.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create)